# Qt : How to open a pdf file from the application's resources?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to create a push button that will open a .doc or a .pdf file. It only works when I use a `QFileDialog` like this:

```
QString docName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Arquivos"), "C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/HEMODIALISE/Hemodialise/Resources/Documentos", "All files (*.*)");

QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///"+docName, QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

But I want to open instantly using just the file inside the resources of the program.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: do you want to see a file that is in the qrc?

Comment: It is better to use this code for opening of external file: `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(docName))`.

Comment: Keep in mind any answer to this question assumes the user has applications installed that can handle these file types. That's not a guarantee on every platform Qt supports.

Comment: File inside resources - it not a file. It is a binary array. If you want to open such file in external program - first you need to have a real file. So, possible ways: 1) save file from resources to disk (for example, in temp folder). 2) create a driver that with simulate the file system and work with Qt resources as with file structure. But I believe that you don't need it ;)